# How to use a counter in rabl json file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, counter, rabl

In my rails project, I am using RABL gem for json response.
My current response is as follows:

```
[
{
    "id": 25,
    "name": "Follow ups",
    "steps": [
        {
            "id": 67,
            "Step 1 Subject: ": "Email Test"
        },
        {
            "id": 65,
            "Step 1 Subject: ": "Email Test"
        },
        {
            "id": 66,
            "Step 1 Subject: ": "Email Test"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

I want to use a counter in steps name key, like below:

```
[
{
    "id": 25,
    "name": "Follow ups",
    "steps": [
        {
            "id": 67,
            "Step 1 Subject: ": "Email Test"
        },
        {
            "id": 65,
            "Step 2 Subject: ": "Email Test"
        },
        {
            "id": 66,
            "Step 3 Subject: ": "Email Test"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

How can I run a counter in this file?

Comment: Couldn't you pre process the model to have this counter value in the steps collection?

Comment: @Vadim
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add an index attribute to whatever is your Step class (this shouldn't be a db column). Then you can do this kind of pre-processing in your controller method. Use the index property in the rabl file.

```
def index
  @items = get_items
  @items.each do |item|
    item.steps.each_with_index do |step, index|
      step.index = index
    end
  end
end
```